# Accessing a webpage of localhost from local machine running on remote server

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, server, localhost

I have a windows pc in which I have installed putty through which I am connecting/accessing to a server remotely using ssh .It is a ubuntu20.04 terminal version server.In that ubuntu server I am running one application i.e evebox server which runs on 127.0.0.1:5636.I want to access this site in order to view my logs.I have tried everything but it doesnt work .How should i open this site in a web browser on my local pc

Answer (score 0):

You have to host the server not on your localhost-ip, but on your given ip from the router. For this just run 'hostname -I' or 'ip addr' on your server machine and host the service on that ip. With this, your local pc (router too) knows where to look for.

Keep in mind to modify your firewall accordingly.
Assuming you use ufw, it would be something like 'sudo ufw allow 5636', but take a look at the [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW) regardless (haven't used ufw in a long time).

If you are not using any firewall, there should be no problem.

I hope I could help you!

strange